# How to return NotFound result when using web api documentation

Tags: c#, web, asp.net-web-api

How to indicate that a resource cannot be found and still get auto generated documentation for my Web API 2 web application?

Take for example this method definiition:

```
 public JsonResult<CalculatorDescription> GetParameterInfo(string parameterCaption)
```

If I use this definition I cannot return `NotFound()`, yet if I change the return type to `IHttpActionResult`( in order to be able to return `NotFound()` ) I do not get the auto-generated information for my return type.

Edit: 
Note that I'm using the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337124(v=vs.118).aspx JsonResult and **not** the MVC one ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx )

Comment: The built-in `JsonResult` is a non-generic type. What's `JsonResult<CalculatorDescription>`?

Comment: @haim770 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337124(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Sorry. Missed that.

Comment: @haim770 no problem, its easy to miss that if you work with the mvc classes

Comment: If you're explicitly using `return new JsonResult<CalculatorDescription>(...)` you still don't get the desired type information in response?

Comment: @haim770 using return new JsonResult<CalculatorDescription>(...) I get the relevant documentation auto-generated, but I don't know how to specify a response of not found

Comment: Just change the method signature to return `IHttpActionResult` and use either `return JsonResult<...>(...)` or `return NotFound()` when applicable

Comment: @haim770 that's exactly the problem, I don't get auto-generated documentation if i do this because the documentation analyses the compile time types so there's no way to determine the return type of IHttpActionResult

Comment: Yes you can.  You need to use the `ResponseType` attribute.  See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your return type to `IHttpActionResult`, and decorate your action method with the [`ResponseType` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Use this to specify the entity type returned by an action when the declared return type is HttpResponseMessage or IHttpActionResult. The ResponseType will be read by ApiExplorer when generating ApiDescription.

Then, inside your method, return `NotFound()` or `JsonResult<T>`.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(CalculatorDescription))]
public IHttpActionResult GetParameterInfo(string parameterCaption)
{
    ...
    if (...) 
        return new JsonResult<CalculatorDescription>(...);
    else 
        return NotFound();        
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Just one more thing to add to this, do you have any idea about a tool that does documentation with annonymous types, so I can return annonymous type and not have to create new classes only for return types?

Comment: None that I am aware of, since the only way to get the structure of the response would be to execute the action.  You can in theory make a duplicate of your action that responds only to the OPTIONS verb, that returns a dummy response, but now you're duplicating code.  In my opinion, its easier to just create the model.